# Angular 2 delete value from object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've got 1 array containing objects:

```
one = [
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'}
]
```

I want to delete `key` from all, how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Are you having trouble with the looping, or the deleting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below

```js
const one = [
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
    {name: 'Name', key: '4868466'},
]

const result = one.map((item) => {
 delete item.key
 return item
})

console.log("result:", result)
```

Comment: What if i in delete item.key - I want key to be variable ?

Comment: sorry, i did not get you...can you please make your point more clear?

Comment: I just want that item.key would be item.(myvariable). - not value from array.

Comment: you are saying, in place of 'key', it can be anything, right? for that use, delete item[myVariable]

Comment: Sorry, but one more question what if I want to delete item from array object array ?

Comment: I mean then I should write something item.price.value - but with variable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182744/discussion-between-angulandy2-and-ankush-sharma).

Comment: In that case also, it should be delete item[price.value], only if you know exact key like 'key' or 'name' you have you can use '.' operator. If the value is present in variable use []

Answer (score 3):

One way is to loop through and delete the property

```
one.forEach(o => delete o.key);
```

Comment: If I try one.forEach(o => delete o.this.myVar); it doesnt work.

Comment: it should be o.key (key being the property name that you want to delete)

Comment: actually, @ Angulandy2 trying to delete the key(not a literal) that is present in the variable for that he has to use one.forEach(o => delete o[this.myVar]);